# Программа зависает случайным образом на одной строчке (Java SE8)

Tags: java, email, pop3

Была задача написать программу, получающую сообщения с Microsoft Exchange почты, обрабатывающую текст и вложения, пишущую по результатам обработки в БД информацию и отправляющую на почту квитанции.

Из конфигурационного файла берутся настройки вроде POP3 почты и интервала считывания (сейчас стоит 10 минут). Происходит всё это в потоке в бесконечном цикле. Каждый раз происходит переподключение к серверу входящей почты.

```
                MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Разбирается сообщение №" + k + "сообщений всего " + messages.length);

            Message message = messages[k];//здесь программа неожиданно встаёт

            MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Message message = messages[k]; END");
```

На этой строчке происходит зависание. Не могу понять, в чём дело.

Вот код, где она вызывается.

```html
public void workWithIzmiranMail(Calendar workCalendar){
        Properties props = getPropertiesPOP3(izmPop.port, izmPop.host, izmPop.username);
        
        java.util.Date dateFromFile = izmOther.lastDateTime;
                
        
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(izmPop.username, izmPop.password);
            }
        };
        
        String nameKvitancion = "";
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        
        try (Store store = session.getStore("pop3")) {
            store.connect(izmPop.host, izmPop.username, izmPop.password);
            
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");//меняем папку сообщений на входящие
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            
            
            MessageError.addMessage("Установлено соединение с сервером входящей почты");
            MessageError.addMessage("Сообщений на сервере: " + messages.length);
            
////////////////////////////////////
            int beginMessage = messages.length - izmOther.messageCount;
            beginMessage = (beginMessage < 0) ? 0 : beginMessage;
            
            main_circle: for(int k = beginMessage; k < messages.length; k++){

                java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();
                
                String commStringForMessageIn = "";
                
                MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Разбирается сообщение №" + k + "сообщений всего " + messages.length);
                
                Message message = messages[k];//здесь программа неожиданно встаёт
                
                MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Message message = messages[k]; END");
                
                String formatedMessageSentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(message.getSentDate());

                if(message.getSentDate().compareTo(dateFromFile) < 1)  continue;
                                
                
                String fromAddress = "";
                
                
                
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message.getFrom()[0].toString());
                
                
                
                while (matcher.find()) fromAddress = message.getFrom()[0].toString().substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                
                
                
                
                
                if(!fromAddress.contains(izmOther.mask)) {
                
                    dateFromFile = message.getSentDate();
                    
                
                    
                    writeLastTimeInIni(message.getSentDate());
                    
                
                    
                    izmOther.lastDateTime = message.getSentDate();
                    
                
                    
                    continue;//main_circle
                }
                
                MessageType messageType = getMessageType(message.getSubject());
                
                
                String atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile = "";
                
                StringBuilder atachmentDirName = new StringBuilder("");
                
                if(messageType == MessageType.PROGNOZ){
                    //работаем с телом сообщения
                    
                    commStringForMessageIn = "формализованный текст письма";
                    
                    String textBody;
                    
                    try{
                        textBody = getTextFromMessage(message);
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){
                        //System.out.println("Проблемы при считывании тела письма");
                        MessageError.addError("Не удалось разобрать тело письма ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    
                    try{
                        psIZMIRAN.setInt(1, 1);
                        psIZMIRAN.setString(2, message.getSubject().substring(0, (message.getSubject().length() < 100) ? message.getSubject().length() : 100));
                        //psIZMIRAN.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
                        psIZMIRAN.setBytes(3, null);
                        psIZMIRAN.setString(4, textBody);
                        psIZMIRAN.setTimestamp(5, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(message.getSentDate())));

                        if(psIZMIRAN.executeUpdate() < 1){
                            MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                            workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                            //return;
                            break main_circle;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                else{

                    ArrayList<File> attachList = null;
                    
                    try{
                        attachList = getAtachments(message,atachmentDirName);
                    }
                    catch(MessagingException | IOException ex){
                        //System.out.println("Проблемы при получении вложений");
                        MessageError.addError("Не удалось получить вложения сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    
                    if(messageType == MessageType.UNCNOWN){
                        for(File file:attachList){
                            if(file.getName().indexOf("alert_") != 0) {
                                dateFromFile = message.getSentDate();
                                writeLastTimeInIni(message.getSentDate());
                                deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                izmOther.lastDateTime = message.getSentDate();
                                continue main_circle;//сообщение не соответствует ни одному формату
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    int index = 0;
                    
                    for(File file: attachList){
                        
                        try{
                            psIZMIRAN.setInt(1, (index == 0) ? 1: 0);
                            psIZMIRAN.setString(2,file.getName());
                        }
                        catch(SQLException ex){
                            MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                            deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                            workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                            //return;
                            break main_circle;
                        }
                        
                        atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile += file.getName() + " ";
                        
                        if(file.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                            //текстовое вложение
                            try{
                                psIZMIRAN.setBytes(3, null);
                                psIZMIRAN.setString(4, new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())),"windows-1251"));
                            }
                            catch(SQLException | IOException ex){
                                MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                                deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                                //return;
                                break main_circle;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            //бинарное вложение
                            
                            try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()))){
                            psIZMIRAN.setBinaryStream(3, bis);
                            }
                            catch(IOException ex){
                                MessageError.addError("Не удалось прочитать вложения сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                                deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                                //return;
                                break main_circle;
                            }
                            catch(SQLException ex){
                                MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                                deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                                //return;
                                break main_circle;
                            }
                            
                            try{
                                psIZMIRAN.setString(4, null);
                            }
                            catch(SQLException ex){
                                MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                                deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                                //return;
                                break main_circle;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        try{
                        psIZMIRAN.setTimestamp(5, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(message.getSentDate())));
                        }
                        catch(SQLException ex){
                            MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                            deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                            workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                            //return;
                            break main_circle;
                        }
                        
                        
                        try{
                                if(psIZMIRAN.executeUpdate() < 1){
                                    MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                                    deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                                    workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                                    //return;
                                    break main_circle;
                                }
                            }
                        catch(SQLException ex){
                            MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                            deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                            workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                            //return;
                            break main_circle;
                        }
                        
                        commStringForMessageIn = commStringForMessageIn.concat(file.getName()).concat(", ");
                        
                        index++;
                    }
                    
                    
                    commStringForMessageIn = commStringForMessageIn.substring(0, commStringForMessageIn.lastIndexOf(", "));

                    atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile = atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile.trim(); 
                }
                
                    MessageError.addMessage("Получено " + k + "-ое сообщение");
                    MessageError.addMessage("Время ".concat(k+"-го сообщения ").concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                    MessageError.addMessage("Адрес отправителя ".concat(k+"-го сообщения ").concat(fromAddress));
                    MessageError.addMessage("Тема ".concat(k+"-го сообщения ").concat(message.getSubject()));
                    //MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в IZMIAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));

                    String kvitancion = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(message.getSentDate()).
                            concat("\r\n").
                            concat(message.getSubject()).
                            concat("\r\n").
                            concat((atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile.length() > 0) ? atachmentsStringInKvitancionFile.concat("\r\n") : "").
                            concat("0");

                
                    try{
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setString(1, "ИЗМИРАН");
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setString(2, "e-mail");
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setString(3, message.getSubject().substring(0, (message.getSubject().length() < 100) ? message.getSubject().length() : 100));
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setTimestamp(4, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(message.getSentDate())));
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setTimestamp(5, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(currentDate)));
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setTimestamp(6, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date())));
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setString(7, commStringForMessageIn);
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setInt(8, 0);
                        psMESSAGE_IN.setInt(9, 0);
                        //psMESSAGE_IN.registerOutParameter(10, Types.INTEGER);
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }

                    int idFromMessage_IN;

                    try{
                        //ResultSet retSet = psMESSAGE_IN.executeQuery();
//                        if(retSet.first()){
                            //idFromMessage_IN = retSet.getInt("id_mes");
                            psMESSAGE_IN.executeQuery();
                            idFromMessage_IN = psMESSAGE_IN.getInt(10);
                            //MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
//                        }
//                        else
//                        {
//                            MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
//                            deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
//                            workCalendar.setTime(new Date());
//                            return;
//                        }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }


                    try {
                        nameKvitancion = sendMessage(izmSmtp.host,izmSmtp.port,izmSmtp.password,izmSmtp.from,fromAddress,kvitancion,nameKvitancion);
                        //nameKvitancion = sendMessage(izmSmtp.host,izmSmtp.port,izmSmtp.password,izmSmtp.from,"hps@mcc.rsa.ru",kvitancion,nameKvitancion);
                    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                        MessageError.addError("Не удалось отправить квитанцию сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate).concat(" на адрес ").concat(fromAddress));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    
                    try{
                        psDELIVERY_RECEIPT.setInt(1, idFromMessage_IN);
                        psDELIVERY_RECEIPT.setString(2, nameKvitancion);
                        psDELIVERY_RECEIPT.setString(3, kvitancion);

                    if(psDELIVERY_RECEIPT.executeUpdate() > 0)
                    {
                        //MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в DeliveryReceipt сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                    }
                    else{
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу DeliveryReceipt сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу DeliveryReceipt сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }
                    
                    try {
                        izmiranConnection.commit();
                        MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate)); 
                        MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в таблицу MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        MessageError.addMessage("Отправлена квитанция сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        MessageError.addMessage("Прошла запись в таблицу DeliveryReceipt сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу IZMIRAN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate)); 
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу MESSAGE_IN сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));   
                        MessageError.addError("Не прошла запись в таблицу DeliveryReceipt сообщения ".concat(formatedMessageSentDate));
                        deleteDirectory(new File(atachmentDirName.toString()));
                        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                        //return;
                        break main_circle;
                    }

                    dateFromFile = message.getSentDate();
                    izmOther.lastDateTime = message.getSentDate();
                    writeLastTimeInIni(message.getSentDate());//в конце после всех обработок
                    
                }

            inbox.close(false);
        }
        catch(MessagingException ex){
            //System.out.println("Ошибка при подключении к серверу входящей почты");
            MessageError.addError("Ошибка при подключении к серверу входящей почты ".concat(izmPop.host).concat("/").concat(ex.getMessage()));
            workCalendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            return;
        }
        
        workCalendar.setTime(new java.util.Date());
    }
```

Вот настройки подключения к серверу входящей почты.

```
    private static Properties getPropertiesPOP3(String port, String host, String userName){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*");
    props.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
    props.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
    props.put("mail.pop3.user", userName);
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
    return props;
}
```

Вызов функции в бесконечном цикле

```
 @Override
public void run() {



    while(true)
    {          
        //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<начало бесконечного цикла");            

        java.util.Date beginDate = new java.util.Date();//текущее время
        Calendar workC = new GregorianCalendar();
        workC.setTime(beginDate);//текущее время

        //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Действие перед функцией обработки писем");

        workWithIzmiranMail(workC);

        //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Действие после функции обработки писем");

        try {
            izmiranConnection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            MessageError.addError("Не удалось произвести откат записи данных в БД");
        }

        long interval = workC.getTime().getTime() - beginDate.getTime();//разница в миллисекундах между временем окончания работы и временем начала работы

        //SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(message.getSentDate());

        //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Время начала " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(beginDate.getTime()) + "время конца работы " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(workC.getTime()));

        if(interval < (izmOther.interval * 60000)){
            try {

                long sleepTime = izmOther.interval * 60000 - interval;

                //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Действие перед задержкой в " + sleepTime + " мс");

                if(sleepTime > 0) sleep(sleepTime);

                //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Действие после задержки в " + sleepTime + " мс");

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                MessageError.addError("Ошибка в задержке цикла при повторном коннекте");
            }
        }
        //MessageError.addMessage("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<конец бесконечного цикла"); 
    }


}
```

Вот импорты

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.ini4j.Wini;
```

Подскажите. Как понять из-за чего происходит такая дурацкая ошибка? Вроде всё делал, как пишут другие пользователи.

Comment: Зависание происходит случайным образом. Программа может неделю работать, а потом зависнуть на этой строчке.

Comment: а как определили что именно на этой строке? потому что она не очень выглядит опасной